# OpenCV error using g++ to compile (Mountain Lion 10.8)

Tags: opencv, g++, osx-mountain-lion

so I recently got OpenCV built on my mac using homebrew and I attempted to run the following *hello,world* ish program that I got from a stackoverflow user when I got an error.

Here is the program:

```
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h"
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv/highgui.h"

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
  cvNamedWindow( "My Window", 1 );
  IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
  CvFont font;
  double hScale = 1.0;
  double vScale = 1.0;
  int lineWidth = 1;
  cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX | CV_FONT_ITALIC,
              hScale, vScale, 0, lineWidth );
  cvPutText( img, "Hello World!", cvPoint( 200, 400 ), &font,
             cvScalar( 255, 255, 0 ) );
  cvShowImage( "My Window", img );
  cvWaitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the subsequent error: (command to compile was `g++ lol.cpp`)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvCreateImage", referenced from:
      _main in ccxOWdix.o
  "_cvInitFont", referenced from:
      _main in ccxOWdix.o
  "_cvNamedWindow", referenced from:
      _main in ccxOWdix.o
  "_cvPutText", referenced from:
      _main in ccxOWdix.o
  "_cvShowImage", referenced from:
      _main in ccxOWdix.o
  "_cvWaitKey", referenced from:
      _main in ccxOWdix.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the libraries. Have a look at "4) Configure your own projects to use OpenCV" here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

Comment: Well that was  quick solution. Thanks!